# Accessing page post via Facebook Graph API GET URL from iOS, returning "Unsupported get request."

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am a newbie in IOS.
am trying to call Facebook Graph URL to get JSON data & parse it-

```
NSString *urlStr = @"https://graph.facebook.com/102555409843504_373792589386450";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
    NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
```

But its returning error-

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

-I have a valid session, but not sure how to call the graph API with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request this URL in your browser you'll get the same result:

https://graph.facebook.com/102555409843504_373792589386450

The issue is that you are not passing along an `access_token`. So the proper way to retrieve the data is:

https://graph.facebook.com/102555409843504_373792589386450?access_token=SECRET

For testing purposes, you can grab yourself a token from the Graph API explorer, over at:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer